# Uber api returns null

Tags: android, uber-api

I'm trying to display the fare estimates of uber in my android app, using retrofit to load data from api, I even receive status code=200 (which is was it should be acc to uber's [docs](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/estimates-price-get)), but my prices list is null always no matter what co-ordinates i select.

```
**retrofit interface class.**

    public interface PriceEstimate {

    @GET("/v1.2/estimates/price")
    Call<Prices> getEstimate(@Header("Authorization") String authToken,
                                 @Query("start_latitude") float start_latitude,
                                 @Query("start_longitude") float start_longitude,
                                 @Query("end_latitude") float stop_latitude,
                                 @Query("end_longitude") float stop_longitude);
}
```

Price Class:

```
public class Prices {
    public List<PriceModel> prices;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
public List<PriceModel> getPrices() {
    return prices;
}

public void setPrices(List<PriceModel> prices) {
    this.prices = prices;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

Price Model:

```
 public class PriceModel {

    private String localizedDisplayName;
    private Double distance;
    private String displayName;
    private String productId;
    private Object highEstimate;
    private Object lowEstimate;
    private Integer duration;
    private String estimate;
    private Object currencyCode;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public String getLocalizedDisplayName() {
        return localizedDisplayName;
    }

    public void setLocalizedDisplayName(String localizedDisplayName) {
        this.localizedDisplayName = localizedDisplayName;
    }

    public Double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(Double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public Object getHighEstimate() {
        return highEstimate;
    }

    public void setHighEstimate(Object highEstimate) {
        this.highEstimate = highEstimate;
    }

    public Object getLowEstimate() {
        return lowEstimate;
    }

    public void setLowEstimate(Object lowEstimate) {
        this.lowEstimate = lowEstimate;
    }

    public Integer getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(Integer duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getEstimate() {
        return estimate;
    }

    public void setEstimate(String estimate) {
        this.estimate = estimate;
    }

    public Object getCurrencyCode() {
        return currencyCode;
    }

    public void setCurrencyCode(Object currencyCode) {
        this.currencyCode = currencyCode;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }


}
```

Activity

```
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
                PriceEstimate service=retrofit.create(PriceEstimate.class);
                Call<Prices> call=service.getEstimate(token,pick_lats,pick_Long,drop_lats,drop_Long);//token=server_token
                call.enqueue(new Callback<Prices>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Prices> call, Response<Prices> response) {
                       List<PriceModel> prices;
                        prices=response.body().getPrices();//this is null always

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Prices> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

**Complete JSON log**

```
 {  
   "body":{  
      "additionalProperties":{  

      },
      "prices":[  

      ]
   },
   "rawResponse":{  
      "body":{  
         "contentLength":13,
         "contentType":{  
            "mediaType":"application/json",
            "subtype":"json",
            "type":"application"
         }
      },
      "code":200,
      "handshake":{  
         "cipherSuite":{  
            "javaName":"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
         },
         "localCertificates":[  

         ],
         "peerCertificates":[  
            {  
               "type":"X.509"
            },
            {  
               "type":"X.509"
            },
            {  
               "type":"X.509"
            }
         ],
         "tlsVersion":"TLS_1_2"
      },
      "headers":{  
         "namesAndValues":[  
            "Server",
            "nginx",
            "Date",
            "Sat, 16 Sep 2017 16:25:39 GMT",
            "Content-Type",
            "application/json",
            "Content-Length",
            "13",
            "Connection",
            "keep-alive",
            "Content-Geo-System",
            "wgs-84",
            "Content-Language",
            "en",
            "Etag",
            "\"170e362581d1816dbaf082a7ac196cba26bbc4f7\"",
            "X-Uber-App",
            "uberex-nonsandbox",
            "X-Uber-App",
            "optimus",
            "Strict-Transport-Security",
            "max-age\u003d604800",
            "X-Content-Type-Options",
            "nosniff",
            "X-XSS-Protection",
            "1; mode\u003dblock",
            "Strict-Transport-Security",
            "max-age\u003d2592000",
            "X-Frame-Options",
            "SAMEORIGIN",
            "Cache-Control",
            "max-age\u003d0"
         ]
      },
      "message":"OK",
      "networkResponse":{  
         "code":200,
         "handshake":{  
            "cipherSuite":{  
               "javaName":"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
            },
            "localCertificates":[  

            ],
            "peerCertificates":[  
               {  
                  "type":"X.509"
               },
               {  
                  "type":"X.509"
               },
               {  
                  "type":"X.509"
               }
            ],
            "tlsVersion":"TLS_1_2"
         },
         "headers":{  
            "namesAndValues":[  
               "Server",
               "nginx",
               "Date",
               "Sat, 16 Sep 2017 16:25:39 GMT",
               "Content-Type",
               "application/json",
               "Content-Length",
               "13",
               "Connection",
               "keep-alive",
               "Content-Geo-System",
               "wgs-84",
               "Content-Language",
               "en",
               "Etag",
               "\"170e362581d1816dbaf082a7ac196cba26bbc4f7\"",
               "X-Uber-App",
               "uberex-nonsandbox",
               "X-Uber-App",
               "optimus",
               "Strict-Transport-Security",
               "max-age\u003d604800",
               "X-Content-Type-Options",
               "nosniff",
               "X-XSS-Protection",
               "1; mode\u003dblock",
               "Strict-Transport-Security",
               "max-age\u003d2592000",
               "X-Frame-Options",
               "SAMEORIGIN",
               "Cache-Control",
               "max-age\u003d0"
            ]
         },
         "message":"OK",
         "protocol":"HTTP_1_1",
         "receivedResponseAtMillis":1505576817826,
         "request":{  
            "cacheControl":{  
               "immutable":false,
               "isPrivate":false,
               "isPublic":false,
               "maxAgeSeconds":-1,
               "maxStaleSeconds":-1,
               "minFreshSeconds":-1,
               "mustRevalidate":false,
               "noCache":false,
               "noStore":false,
               "noTransform":false,
               "onlyIfCached":false,
               "sMaxAgeSeconds":-1
            },
            "headers":{  
               "namesAndValues":[  
                  "Authorization",
                  "Token wegHf8ihFOzW2TI7pefdVz7xkst_cC3oXLvMhtmW",
                  "Host",
                  "api.uber.com",
                  "Connection",
                  "Keep-Alive",
                  "Accept-Encoding",
                  "gzip",
                  "User-Agent",
                  "okhttp/3.8.0"
               ]
            },
            "method":"GET",
            "tag":{  
               "headers":{  
                  "namesAndValues":[  
                     "Authorization",
                     "Token wegHf8ihFOzW2TI7pefdVz7xkst_cC3oXLvMhtmW"
                  ]
               },
               "method":"GET",
               "url":{  
                  "host":"api.uber.com",
                  "password":"",
                  "pathSegments":[  
                     "v1.2",
                     "estimates",
                     "price"
                  ],
                  "port":443,
                  "queryNamesAndValues":[  
                     "start_latitude",
                     "17.368908",
                     "start_longitude",
                     "17.368908",
                     "end_latitude",
                     "17.413828",
                     "end_longitude",
                     "17.413828"
                  ],
                  "scheme":"https",
                  "url":"https://api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/price?start_latitude\u003d17.368908\u0026start_longitude\u003d17.368908\u0026end_latitude\u003d17.413828\u0026end_longitude\u003d17.413828",
                  "username":""
               }
            },
            "url":{  
               "host":"api.uber.com",
               "password":"",
               "pathSegments":[  
                  "v1.2",
                  "estimates",
                  "price"
               ],
               "port":443,
               "queryNamesAndValues":[  
                  "start_latitude",
                  "17.368908",
                  "start_longitude",
                  "17.368908",
                  "end_latitude",
                  "17.413828",
                  "end_longitude",
                  "17.413828"
               ],
               "scheme":"https",
               "url":"https://api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/price?start_latitude\u003d17.368908\u0026start_longitude\u003d17.368908\u0026end_latitude\u003d17.413828\u0026end_longitude\u003d17.413828",
               "username":""
            }
         },
         "sentRequestAtMillis":1505576817197
      },
      "protocol":"HTTP_1_1",
      "receivedResponseAtMillis":1505576817826,
      "request":{  
         "headers":{  
            "namesAndValues":[  
               "Authorization",
               "Token wegHf8ihFOzW2TI7pefdVz7xkst_cC3oXLvMhtmW"
            ]
         },
         "method":"GET",
         "url":{  
            "host":"api.uber.com",
            "password":"",
            "pathSegments":[  
               "v1.2",
               "estimates",
               "price"
            ],
            "port":443,
            "queryNamesAndValues":[  
               "start_latitude",
               "17.368908",
               "start_longitude",
               "17.368908",
               "end_latitude",
               "17.413828",
               "end_longitude",
               "17.413828"
            ],
            "scheme":"https",
            "url":"https://api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/price?start_latitude\u003d17.368908\u0026start_longitude\u003d17.368908\u0026end_latitude\u003d17.413828\u0026end_longitude\u003d17.413828",
            "username":""
         }
```

Comment: what does `response.body()` return?

Comment: when i use debugger to check the value of body object  it shows these -------         additionalProperties = {HashMap@5000}  size = 0
prices = {ArrayList@5001}  size = 0
shadow$_klass_ = {Class@4859} "class com.sohail.farecompare.Prices"
shadow$_monitor_ = -2006322734

Comment: log your json response in logcat and post that here

Comment: updated the post please check it out

Comment: well the prices attribute of the JSON Object is empty so it is normal that the arraylist is empty. You should check if you are calling the API with the correct attributes

Comment: As far as i know i'm calling it the way it is meant to be , don't know what the problem here is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found my own mistake , just sharing here so that it could help someone in future.

I was passing my co-ordinates incorrectly for latitudes i passed my longitudes value and vice versa. feel really stupid after wasting my time behind it